# Взаимодействие Java-кода с библиотекой .dll с com-интерфейсом

Tags: java, c#, com

Всем привет! Ребята, нужна ваша помощь: пишу программу на Java, которая взаимодействует с приложением через com-интерфейс (использую библиотеку jacob).
Мой код на Java выглядит так (закомментила строку, с проблемной функцией, а так все прекрасно работает):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Dispatch app, game, timerNow, timePeriod, timeOver, timeOut, logic;
    char state, tpstate, tovstate, toustate;
    try
    {
        Variant n0ll = new Variant(null);
        app = new Dispatch("SuperVision2:Application");
        game = Dispatch.get(app, "Game").toDispatch();
        logic = Dispatch.call(app, "IceHockeyLogic").toDispatch();
        //tagPTY_STATE state = new tagPTY_STATE();
        timePeriod = Dispatch.call(game, "Timer", new Variant(1)).toDispatch();
        timeOver = Dispatch.call(game, "Timer", new Variant(5)).toDispatch();
        timeOut = Dispatch.call(game, "Timer", new Variant(4)).toDispatch();
        //Dispatch.call(logic, "get_PtyState", new Variant(1), state);
        while (true) {
            try {
                timerNow = Dispatch.call(game, "Timer", n0ll).toDispatch();
                state = (Dispatch.get(timerNow, "Direction").getBoolean()) ? 'u' : 'd';
                tpstate = (Dispatch.get(timePeriod, "Active").getBoolean()) ? '1' : '0';
                toustate = (Dispatch.get(timeOut, "Active").getBoolean()) ? '1' : '0';
                tovstate = (Dispatch.get(timeOver, "Active").getBoolean()) ? '1' : '0';
                System.out.println(tpstate + "" + toustate + "" + tovstate + (Dispatch.get(game, "Period")).toInt() + Dispatch.get(timerNow, "Id") + " " + Dispatch.get(timerNow, "Interval") + " " + Dispatch.get(timerNow, "Value") + " " + state);
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

В коде используется com.jacob.com.Dispatch и com.jacob.com.Variant из библиотеки Jacob.
Посмотрела com-интерфейс нужной .dll через OleView, никак не могу вызвать следующую функцию, которая находится в единственной закомментированной строке:

```
[hidden, helpstring("Получить информацию")]
HRESULT get_PtyState(
[in] unsigned int nIndex, 
[in, out] tagPTY_STATE* pState);
```

Потому, что у меня нет объекта `tagPTY_STATE pState`. Получить его из приложения невозможно, нигде нет возвращаемого значения подобного типа, все библиотеки в приложении уже посмотрела. Зато в той же библиотеке есть вот такая структура:

```
typedef struct tagtagPTY_STATE {
unsigned long cbSize; 
unsigned int mask; 
unsigned long nPtyMsecs; 
unsigned long nPtyIntervalMsecs; 
unsigned int nNumber; 
unsigned int state; 
unsigned int stateMask;
} tagPTY_STATE;
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне в моем Java-приложении создать объект, который был бы экземпляром этой структуры, чтобы потом, с помощью этого объекта вызвать функцию `get_PtyState`?

Comment: Все остальные функции, для запуска которых не нужно создавать новых объектов, у меня нормально вызываются и работают и в Java. Писать на другом языке - не вариант, хотя я уже и написала эту часть своего приложения на c#, и программа у меня исправно работает - но все равно, мне хотелось бы, чтобы приложение было полностью написано на Java, без подобных костылей.

Comment: Ох не хорошее это дело все в `try/catch` оборачивать, тем более если все равно вы экзепшны пробрасываете машине jvm которая упадет и кинет логи в консоль.

Comment: А если вызвать `Dispatch.getIDOfName(logic, "get_PtyState")` то что получится?

Comment: Кстати, при чем тут C#?

Comment: На C# написана библиотека, содержащая вот эту структуру, или я все же ошибаюсь, и это C++? Насколько я помню, проблема была в том, что Jacob (библиотека для работы с com-объектами в Java), не поддерживает вызов подобных функций, где требуется создать объект какой-либо структуры. У меня всегда вылетало UnsupportedOperationException . Решила проблему путем написания небольшого приложения на том же C#, которое, в свою очередь, вызывается из моей Java-программы. С учетом прошедшего времени, для меня эта проблема, честно говоря, уже не особо и актуальна : костыль, но работает.

Answer (score -1):

Класс будет такой:

```
class tagPTY_STATE {

    long cbSize,
            nPtyMsecs,
            nPtyIntervalMsecs;

    int mask,
            nNumber,
            state,
            stateMask;
}
```

Comment: Ну это в принципе мне понятно. То есть мне нужно просто создать объект вышеописанного класса прямо в Java, отправить его в ту c#-овскую функцию, и все будет работать?

Comment: Вполне ожидаемо при попытке отправки вызова функции: tagPTY_STATE state = new tagPTY_STATE();//поля инициализируются в конструкторе
Dispatch res = Dispatch.call(logic, "get_PtyState", new Variant(i), new Variant(state)).toDispatch();
вылетает
Exception in thread "main" com.jacob.com.NotImplementedException: populateVariant() not implemented for class tagPTY_STATE

Comment: @lenochkadobryakova, не совсем понятно. Если вы пытаетесь взаимодействовать с неким сервисом, вам потребуется обвертка. Иначе я просто не понимаю, что вы делаете. К тому же для более верного ответа, вам необходимо более подробно оформить ваш вопрос (желательно дополнить текущий), ибо даже не понятно - как вы пытаетесь взаимодействовать и что делаете.

Comment: Добавила свой код. Я так поняла, что нужно каким-то образом описать эту структуру в отдельном классе, создать объект и отправить его в эту функцию, только как это сделать?

Comment: Как минимум вижу, что `tagPTY_STATE` вы не верно передаете. Вам же нужно инициализировать объект этого класса, где будут заполнены конкретные свойства этого класса. А вы делаете не то, что нужно.  к тому же `new Variant != new tagPTY_STATE`. вы могли бы сделать `tagPTY_STATE state = new tagPTY_STATE();` и уже конкретно `state` передавать, а не `new Variant(state)`.

Comment: Ну да, я понимаю, что мне нужно каким-то образом создать в Java экземпляр структуры, пробовала сама писать класс, указанный в вашем ответе (с учетом того, что здесь не хватает одного поля int mask), и посылать в функцию объект, объявленный именно так, как вы сейчас написали, но все равно Exception вываливается. Пробовала оборачивать этот объект в Variant, но, насколько я поняла, это невозможно, нужно посылать объект без обертки. Как раз в том и проблема, что я знаю, как правильно объявить этот объект, но не знаю, как написать класс для этих объектов.

Comment: @lenochkadobryakova, mask пропустил, да, поправил пост. - метод `get_PtyState` - у  этого метода 2 параметра `int` и `tagPTY_STATE`. `int` != `new Variant` у вас по структуре видно, что метод `get_PtyState(int nIndex, tagPTY_STATE* pState);` а значит он ждет число и объект `tagPTY_STATE`

Comment: Ну это верно, если писать на плюсах или шарпе, согласна, я это знаю. Но для использования библиотеки jacob нужно все передавамые объекты или примитивы в Variant оборачивать. Вот в моем коде выше видно, что даже null приходится в Variant оборачивать, чтобы функцию Timer() вызвать. Или вот строка, к примеру: timePeriod = Dispatch.call(game, "Timer", new Variant(1)).toDispatch(); . Здесь так же нужен int, но приходится оборачивать, иначе - не работает, а так - все нормально. Поэтому этот момент у меня сомнений не вызывает, и это - не проблема. У меня класса нужного нет, вот это да.